# Django 1.6: Change URL structure

Tags: python, django, url, redirect

I've a database of doctors and I would like to change their url structure:

The current url is: `localhost:8000/docprofile/32/`

## old views.py

```
def showDocProfile(request, id):
    doctor = get_object_or_404(Doctor, id=id)

    d = getVariables(request,dictionary={'page_name': "Dr." + doctor.name+"" })

    d.update({'doctor': doctor, 'doctors': Doctor.objects.all()})
    return render(request, 'm1/docprofile.html', d)
```

## old urls.py

```
url(r'^docprofile/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.showDocProfile, name='showDocProfile'),
```

The new url is `localhost:8000/doctor/john-doe/`

## new views.py

```
def showDocProfile(request, slug):
    doctor = get_object_or_404(Doctor, slug=slug)

    d = getVariables(request,dictionary={'page_name': "Dr." + doctor.name+"" })

    d.update({'doctor': doctor, 'doctors': Doctor.objects.all()})
    return render(request, 'm1/docprofile.html', d)
```

## new urls.py

```
url(r'^doctor/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.showDocProfile, name='showDocProfile'),
```

I successfully changed the url.

My problem is how do I do a permanent 301 url redirect such that if someone visits `localhost:8000/docprofile/32/` it's redirected to `localhost:8000/doctor/john-doe/`?

Comment: keep old url and old views, whenever a request comes, do redirect to new url from your old views.

Comment: @GeoJacob How do I do that? I'm quite new to Django.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add these to your files.

**Views.py**

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def showDocProfileOld(request, id):
   doctor = get_object_or_404(Doctor, id=id)

   return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('showDocProfile', args=[doctor.slug]))

def showDocProfile(request, slug):
   doctor = get_object_or_404(Doctor, slug=slug)

   d = getVariables(request,dictionary={'page_name': "Dr." + doctor.name+"" })

   d.update({'doctor': doctor, 'doctors': Doctor.objects.all()})
   return render(request, 'm1/docprofile.html', d)
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^doctor/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.showDocProfile, name='showDocProfile'),
url(r'^docprofile/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.showDocProfileOld, name='showDocProfileOld'),
```

Comment: @joe Thanks a lot for the answer. Just one correction. HttpResponseRedirect is a temporary direction. It gives a http status code 302. I wanted a permanent redirect with a status code 301. So i just changed it to HttpResponsePermanentRedirect.